# Trying access a database in an Android App

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, csv

This is more of an advice question. I'm building and app that one of the functions will allow the user to pick the make, model, year and transmission of their car. There will be 4 drop-down menus.

- Make
- Model
- Year
- Transmission

At the start, all but the first drop-down menu will be disabled. When the user chooses a car "make" from the first drop-down, the second drop-down, Models, will then become enabled and will only display the "models" for the user selected "make". If the user selects FORD for the first option, the second drop-down will be populated with ford models only, i.e. FOCUS, MUSTANG etc.

I built a web version of this a while ago and the way I did it was after every user choice, I queried a database, populated the next drop-down and then refreshed the page. The database was just to hold information to be accessed by the user. The database was not used to hold any user information, just data about cars. The way I inserted information into the database was from a .CSV file.

My question to you is this. Since the app only requires information to be pulled, not inserted, do we even need a database? Or should we just include the .CSV file (~3mb) in the APP and query that?

At this time, I'm really leaning towards just including the .CSV file in the APP installation. If you think we still need a database, what would be a good option? (MySQL or SQLite).

Answer (score 1):

a good read on Android storage options is located [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

If you are only reading the data, I suggest you to use the built in [String-Arrays](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) in the resources. There you can put your data in different arrays and then read from there via [`getStringArray(int resid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29)